# Python regex with ÅÄÖ (utf-8) in Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: python, regex, utf-8, bash, python-3.4

I'm trying to split a string containing Swedish characters with re.split, but I can't get the code to work.

```
wordsre = re.compile(r"[\WåäöÅÄÖ]+")
mytext = "hej. och gå! Med en #katt som leker 9 liv!"
newtext = wordsre.split(mytext)
```

The output is:

```
['hej', 'och', 'g', 'Med', 'en', 'katt', 'som', 'leker', '9', 'liv', '']
```

EDIT: The third word is supposed to be "gå". The Swedish character "å" is missing.

I'm on Mac OS X Mavericks, using Python 3.4 and "locale" in Terminal (Bash) outputs:

```
LANG="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I've found this thread on Ubuntu Forum, but I can't see why it's not working for me although the locale is correct.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1534940

Comment: The output is exactly what I'd expect. What exactly did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: I expected it to say: ['hej', 'och', 'gå', 'Med', 'en', 'katt', 'som', 'leker', '9', 'liv', ''] - sorry for not a very good example text. Missing the "å".

Comment: Then *don't include `å` in the split expression*! Any character in your `[...]` character class is split on, the `å` is included in that.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve here? Why are you including those characters in the character class to split on in the first place?

Comment: You're right. I've misunderstood the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html: "\W - When the LOCALE and UNICODE flags are not specified, matches any non-alphanumeric character; this is equivalent to the set [^a-zA-Z0-9_]. I thought it wouldn't catch åäöÅÄÖ but it did.

Comment: You are getting confused by an inverse there; `[^...]` matches *everything **not** in the set*. So `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` would not match `a` (it is explicitly excluded) but it *would* match `å`. But by default `UNICODE` is on when using a `str` pattern (as you did) and then `å` and other such letters are excluded by `\W`, included in `\w`. So they are *excluded* by `\W`, but you *added them back in*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Small Typo: use `\w`, not `\W`

This will work:

```
[\wåäöÅÄÖ]+
```

In Python:

```
print(re.findall(r"[\wåäöÅÄÖ]+","hej. och gå! Med en #katt som leker 9 liv!"))
```

Output:

```
['hej', 'och', 'gå', 'Med', 'en', 'katt', 'som', 'leker', '9', 'liv']
```

**Explanation**

- `\W` matches chars that are not letters, digits or underscores, which is the opposite of what we want to match the words
- In Python 2, `\w` matches an ASCII letter, digit or underscore (unless, as @MartijnPieters points out, you use the `re.UNICODE` option)
- In Python 3, `\w` matches a unicode letter, ideogram, digit or underscore, (unless, as @MartijnPieters points out, you use the `re.ASCII` option) so the accented letters are unneeded (`\w+` is enough)

Comment: The characters `åäöÅÄÖ` are *already included* in `\w`. There is no need to list them. The OP was *splitting* however, not using `re.findall()`, so *just* `\W+` works.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good point—true for Python 3, untrue for Python 2. Mattias tagged the question Python 3, so the short version will work. Adding it to the explanation.

Comment: In Python 2, the same applies if you use a Unicode string for the pattern or set `re.UNICODE` explicitly.

Comment: And in Python 3, you can still use a *bytes* pattern and/or use `re.ASCII` to get the ASCII-only behaviour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I added these last details because it's a treat being in touch with you—and it enriches the answer, and it's a lazy Sunday (Saturday for you)... But I must say that I don't usually go to that level of detail when explaining tokens. :) Maybe I should—although I fear that at some stage detailed answers start to scare people away, as I've sometimes experienced: the idea that shorter is always better.

Comment: Sure, but you had *incorrect* information that needed correcting. This is not about Python 2 vs. 3 but about Unicode vs. byte strings, really.

Answer (score 3):

You are *including* `å` in the characters to split on. It appears you have misunderstood what the split *does*.

`re.split()` will split the words on anything that matches the characters class; in your case that means anything `\W` matches (anything that is **not** a letter, a number or `_`), and you added the characters `åÅäÄöÖ` to that set.

**Omit** those characters if you don't want them to be split on:

```
wordsre = re.compile(r"\W+")
```

In a Unicode regular expression, they are not part of the `\W` character set to begin with.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> mytext = "hej. och gå! Med en #katt som leker 9 liv!"
>>> wordsre = re.compile(r"\W+")
>>> wordsre.split(mytext)
['hej', 'och', 'gå', 'Med', 'en', 'katt', 'som', 'leker', '9', 'liv', '']
```

As `\w` is the inverse of `\W`, you can also use `re.findall()` instead of `re.split()`, using the `\w` pattern to extract the words rather than remove the non-word characters:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', mytext)
['hej', 'och', 'gå', 'Med', 'en', 'katt', 'som', 'leker', '9', 'liv']
```

with the added advantage that there now is no trailing empty string left.

Again, when using a Unicode pattern, *all* letters are included, the character set is not limited to just the ASCII letter characters.

Answer (score 1):

Get the matched group from index 1

```
([^\s]+)
```

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nO7jF9/9)

OR try

```
(\S+)
```

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nO7jF9/10)

As per you expected output use below regex that excludes spaces, dot, hash and explanatory sign.

```
([^\s\.#!]+)
```

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nO7jF9/12)

---

sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'([^\s]+)')
test_str = u"hej. och gå! Med en #katt som leker 9 liv!"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```